# How the output has 4 items in the array?

Tags: javascript

```
    var arr =[1,2,3,4];
      var ct = arr.length;
      for( var i=0;i<ct;i++){
        ct--;
        arr[i]+=i;
      }
      console.log(arr);//1,3,3,4
```

Explain the code, it's confusing me.

Comment: Why not just step through it in the debugger? (And why *wouldn't* it have four items in the array? You don't do anything to change the length of the array.)

Comment: What did you expect to get? You're not mutating the array itself, only values of some of the memebers.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/9cp4gsrd/1/ logs would help you understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop run 2 times.

First time with i = 0, first item in array increase 0 -> 1

Second time with i= 1, second item in array increase 1 -> 3

The ct decrease so that your loop can not reach third time, array item remain keep old value.

Comment: With `i == 0` the first item doesn't increase; it's adding `0`. That's why it's still `1` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are not really changing the size of the array.

1. You create an array with 4 elements (length = 4)
2. You record the length into an integer, this is a copy of the value
3. Inside the loop, you decrease the value of `ct`, which is a copy of the length, so it does not effect the array at all
4. You increase the current element of the array by what `i` is at the time, so for the first iteration of the loop, you do `1 + 0`

So you see, no changes are made to the length of the array, only the values that the array contains.